# How to tackle the problem of differentiating a quotient expression smartly?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The expressions which I am interested in are given by:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle f_{1}(a,b) = a\left[\frac{1 + 2(\theta - 1)b - \sqrt{[1+2(\theta-1)b]^{2} - 4\theta(\theta-1)b^{2}}}{2b(\theta - 1)}\right]\\\\
\displaystyle f_{2}(a,b) = \left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)\left[\frac{1 - \sqrt{[1 + 2(\theta - 1)a]^{2} - 4\theta(\theta - 1)a^{2}}}{2(\theta -1)}\right] + a
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$ where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\theta\neq 1$.

I want to differentiate the first expression with respect to $b$ and the second with respect to $a$.

I know the properties of partial differentiation, but I would like to tackle this problem in a "clever" way. By "clever" I mean to not apply the quotient rule directly. Is there any way to solve this problem smartly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $\times$ a cross product? What are the domains? Is $\theta$ a constant? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Sure, I am going to edit it.

Comment: It looks like you're better off applying the divisors to each of the terms individually, including bringing them into the radicals. There will be *lots* of things dividing out. In most cases you will be able to write something like $1/b$ as just $b^{-1}$ etc so no quotient rule will be needed (mostly).

Comment: According to wolfarm, the derivative is a _mess_, so im not sure you can do a lot here...